# DNS lookup to localhost gives network error

Tags: freebsd, dns-hosting, pf, jail, unbound

I am running a recursive DNS server on Unbound in a jail on FreeBSD with pf as a firewall.
Running `drill @xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx example.com` (where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the servers IP) on my local machine yields me with a successful lookup.

However, if I try the same on the server itself, both in the jail and host...

```
# drill @localhost example.com
Error: error sending query: Could not send or receive, because of network error
# drill @xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx example.com
Error: error sending query: Could not send or receive, because of network error
# drill @127.0.0.1 example.com
Error: error sending query: Could not send or receive, because of network error
# drill @10.0.0.1 example.com
Error: error sending query: Could not send or receive, because of network error
```

I have `pass quick on lo0 all` in my pf.conf

Here's my relevant ifconfig:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
    options=600003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x3
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
    nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
lo1: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
    options=600003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
    inet 10.0.0.1 netmask 0xffffff00
    nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
```

The DNS jail is running under 10.0.0.1

A couple of thoughts from my side: Unbound is quite surely configured right. The interface is already 0.0.0.0 and I have access-control rules for 10.0.0.0/16 and 127.0.0.0/8 (and my local machine's IP, of course). Additionally, trying to drill would yield a simple "refused" if anything there was faulty.
So I think it has something to do with pf?
I'm probably missing something small and obvious, but I can't figure out what.

What I'd like to achieve would be a successful `# drill @localhost example.com` on the server so I can replace my resolv.conf nameservers with 127.0.0.1

**Edit:** I've done some testing with netcat, doing `# nc -4 -vv localhost 53` gives me a timeout. Using udp as a protocol with `# nc -4 -w 10 -vv -u localhost 53` however, does not.
Running `# pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.conf`, here's the two redirects to the jail:

```
rdr pass on vtnet0 inet proto udp from any to any port = domain -> 10.0.0.1 port 53
rdr pass on vtnet0 inet proto tcp from any to any port = domain -> 10.0.0.1 port 53
```

Comment: Does `drill @10.0.0.1 example.com` fail?

Comment: Yes. I've tried 10.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, localhost and xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx on both jail and host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more testing the pf rules, I briefly let all traffic pass and realized the mistake was that while I had `pass quick on lo0 all` in the pf.conf, the jail is running under lo1.

I added `pass quick on lo1 all` and it works now.

Also note that from within a jail, you should query the jail IP instead of localhost. So, in the jails resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 10.0.0.1
```

Comment: It's better to use `set skip on lo0`, since you do not filtering on `lo0` at all.